# App won't execute on new Android Studio 2.2 with gradle 2.14.1 with Instant Run enabled

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-2.2, instant-run

I just installed the newer Android Studio 2.2 and I'm in trouble while building my project:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: [path_to_project]/app/build/intermediates/symbols/androidTest/debug/R.txt (No such file or directory)
```

I'm using gradle version 2.14.1 (because this version of the IDE force me to use it).

If I disable instant run everything works ok, but it is a shame to lose all of a sudden this feature.

Any help?

EDIT:

I tried the following but the error still happen:

- Clean the project.
- Re-imported the project as an external source into Android Studio.

Comment: to work properly you should use com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0

Comment: when you start android studio, there is an option to Import project from Eclipse etc. Try importing your project in that manner

Comment: Have you clear whole project once? `Clean Project` Its worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, I had one dependency added two times (one in the normal build plus the same in the test environment). I managed this and instant run worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Try open you terminal on Android Studio and type `gradlew -d assembleDebug` then Clean your project and try again.

Btw, instant run always break something here, i think it's still not really stable, if your error persist, try stop the application and do a clear run.